# How to revert changes to deleted and then recreated file with same content in git to it's state in origin branch?

Tags: git

How to revert changes to deleted and then recreated file in git branch? I want these changes not to appear in `git diff` with `main` branch I've diverged from.

My steps were the following:

1. diverged from `main` branch to branch `test`
2. deleted file `src/patches/axios.patch` (not actual name, I'm using `patch-package` npm package so names are correct in my project for sure)
3. committed change and pushed to remote
4. generated new patch for `axios` with same name in other place (`axios.patch`)
5. copied new patch from step 4 to `src/patches` as `axios.patch`
6. committed changes and pushed to remote
7. now in Github PR page I see same file deleted and same file added
   [image]

I know that I can revert a file to some specific state at some specific commit. In my case it would be `main` branch state when I've diverged from it ( if file changed in meanwhile )?

I've also checked `git diff main` on my branch and there are these changes also present, so it's not Github UI glitch:

```
diff --git a/src/patches/axios.patch b/src/patches/axios.patch
deleted file mode 120000
index fcc8ab7fb..000000000
--- a/src/patches/axios.patch
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-../../patches/axios.patch
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/src/patches/axios.patch b/src/patches/axios.patch
new file mode 100644
index 000000000..fcc8ab7fb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/patches/axios.patch
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+../../patches/axios.patch
\ No newline at end of file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added the file you did not just undo an earlier removal. Notice these two lines in the provided output:

```
deleted file mode 120000
```

and

```
new file mode 100644
```

They mean that you deleted a symbolic link and added a regular file.

To undo the earlier removal, you really have to use

```
git checkout -f main -- src/patches/axios.patch
```

(Modern Git has `git restore` to do the same thing, but I do not know how to operate it---I'm an old-timer.)